# Trying to merge two tables but the expansion result ends with duplicate information

Tags: join, merge, powerbi, powerquery

When I try to merge two columns ([picture of the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMzCM.jpg)), I get 2 tables combined, but when I try to expand it to obtain the specific columns that I want Power Query duplicates the records, going from 438 rows to 999+ rows.

In (1), the upper table is a fact table, and the bottom table is a dimension table (having only unique values). Both columns have the same 'data type'.
In (3) I chose to merge with a Left outer join
In

[image]
if I dont click the check box then I don´t get any coincidence over the records (4)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your question?  If both columns are formatted as text, then there will be zero rows returned if there is no match, and more then the original rows returned if there are multiple matches. You seem to have picked the aproximada/fuzzy match box [x] which would find similar but not identical items, which seem to be returning more than 1 match per project. All of that is working as it should be

Comment: Hello. My objective is to Merge 'Proyectos - Tarifa prom' with 'GLTRAN'. In this case, 'Proyectos - Tarifa prom' has unique values, so what I am trying to do is to match this values with the ones that are in GLTRAN. I guess that with just doing a left join should work but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the matching columns in both tables have the same format

[image]

Then its a simple left outer join.  If there are no matches, then check manually if there should be. I forced a match for image below by having the same value in both tables

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ProjectIDSource"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"ProjectID"}, #"Proyectos - Tarifa prom", {"Codigo protecto"}, "Proyectos - Tarifa prom", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
in  #"Merged Queries"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, they have the same format (data type). The thing is that after I do the merge, I get duplicate information when I expand the new added table, going from 438 rows to 999+ rows

Comment: Then there are more than one match for rows in the the column you are matching. Did you check the raw data for that? What do you want to do in that instance?

Comment: Nope, there is no other match. I did check. The reason for this match is to bring the column 'project fee' which is related to the table projects and comes from the table Projects - Tarifa promedio (same as invoicing)

Comment: So if you click on the matched table that gets returned for a single row , what is being returned ? You look for 1234 and get back what?